# If $f(1+x)=(1-x)^2$ then how to find $f(1-x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I don't understand the process. Also, I don't understand why can't the same method be used as for $f(x+1)=\frac{x+2}{x-3}$ to find $f(x-1)$, where I put 
$$y-1=x+1$$
$$x=y-2$$
$$f(x+1)=\frac{x+2}{x-3}$$
$$f(y-1)=\frac{y-2+2}{y-2+3}=\frac y{y-5}$$
So in the title question I can't put $x+1=-y+1$, but first need to find $f(x)$? Please explain, and thanks in advance.

Comment: The method you wish to apply is unclear, why put $y-1=x+1$ in the first place?

Comment: If you put $x+1=-y+1$ you get $x=-y$ so replacing every $x$ with $y$ you get $f(1-y)=(1+y)^2$ if you change $y$ to $x$ that is exactly what you're asking for $f(1-x)=(1+x)^2$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$f(x-1) = f(0+(x-1)) = f((1-1) + (x-1)) = f(1+x-2) = f(1+(x-2))$$

Now define $x'=x-2$ and use the fact that $f(1+x')=(1-x')^2$.

Answer (score 2):

We know that $f(1+x) = (1-x)^2$. Lets define $u=1+x$ which implies that $x=u-1$. Now we can put $u-1$ instead of $x$ to obtain $$ f(u) = (1-(u-1))^2 = (2-u)^2. $$  Therefore, $f(1-x) = (2-(1-x))^2 = (1+x)^2.$

Answer (score 0):

$f(1+x)=(1-x)^2=(2-(1+x))^2 $

$f(1+(t-1))=f(t)=(1-(t-1))^2=(2-t)^2$

$f(t)=(2-t)^2$

$f(1-x)=(2-(1-x))^2=(x+1)^2$